# SQL Case multiple then condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to do the following in sql? 
I don't seem to be able to get the syntax correct for then with 2 conditions, ie set one declare to an int and concatenate string to another?

```
case 
    when agencyStaff is null
    then @var + 1 & @var2 = @var2 + 'test'
    else 0
```

Comment: No, this is not possible.  In SQL Server, a `SELECT` can either set variables or return results, but not both.

Answer (score 0):

You seem want :

```
select @var2 = coalesce((case when agencyStaff is null 
                              then concat(@var, 1, @var2, 'test') 
                         end), 0
                       );
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "then with two conditions".  A `case` expression is an *expression* that returns a single value.

Perhaps you intend something like this:

```
select (case when agencyStaff is null then 1 else 0 end) as col_1,
       (case when agencyStaff is null then 'test' else '' end) as col_2
```